# undo commit in middle of Git history

Tags: git

I want to undo a single pushed commit that's "in the middle" of the git history, i.e. it's not the most recent commit.

Should I use `git revert <commit hash>`, `git cherry-pick`, or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `git revert <commit hash>`. `git cherry-pick` is for when you want to **redo** a commit.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `git revert <SHA>` to do this. That will ensure that the changes you make are tracked, and if any other developer now pulls in the branch, he will not face issues/conflicts because the histories were out of sync.

On the other hand, using `git cherry-pick` is basically used to pick a commit, and apply it in a different branch, and so won't work here.

You could also have used interactive rebase to undo/squash your changes, but that can very possibly result in conflicts on other developer's machines.